# Firebase and updating the version of the google-services plugin

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, plugins

When I tried to "sync project with Gradle File", two errors appeared in the "build.gradle file (module: app)". A copy of this file is below. The two problematic lines are the first and the fourth implementation of "dependencies", which are:

- **implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'**
- **implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'**

After i tried to sync with Gradle file, the following error message occured :

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>   google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
>   available at
>   https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
>   or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.6.0.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I search for information about that and it seems that the problem is about versioning : but I admit that I do not know which version changed, and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

And please also don't forget to add:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

To your build.gradle file. Please see [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) more info.

Comment: Yes, i tried it this morning and it's working well. The point is... That was what i wrote on the first time... I don't understand how, but now it the programm fully work... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Alex Mamo : I think there are some conflicts between 28.0.0-alpha3 and the latest version of Firebase . I have tried to use v16.0.2 for firebase and it does not work .